# What is the closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n - \frac1{n+1/p}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

A while ago, I started to look at expressions of the following form:
$$
S_p:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n - \frac1{n+1/p},
$$
 where $p$ is prime, because otherwise things get too complicated for me at the moment. 
What I found so far is the following:
$$
S_p= p -\log(2p) - \frac12 \pi \cot\left(\frac\pi p\right) + T_p,
$$
where $T_p$ contains $\frac{p-1}2$ terms $t_{p,k}$ of the form: 
\begin{cases}
\pm 2 \sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2p}\right) \log\left(\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2p}\right)\right) \\
\pm 2 \cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2p}\right) \log\left(\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2p}\right)\right)\\
\pm 2 \sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2p}\right) \log\left(\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2p}\right)\right) 
\\
\pm 2 \cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2p}\right) \log\left(\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2p}\right)\right) 
\end{cases}

An example can be found [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eus8m69pqa9).

> How does the closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n - \frac1{a+n}$ look like? (EDIT: where $a=1/p$)

Comment: Are you looking for this formula?

$$\psi\left(\frac{m}{k}\right) = -\gamma - \log(2k) - \frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{m\pi}{k}\right) + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor\frac{k-1}{2}\rfloor} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi nm}{k}\right)\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{k}\right)\right)$$

where $m$ and $k\;(m < k)$ are positive integers. (Note: I've no idea how to prove this)

Comment: @achillehui looks promising...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| < 1$, we have following expansion

$$-\log(1-z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}$$

Let $\displaystyle\;\omega = e^{\frac{i2\pi}{p}}\;$ be the primitive $p$-root of unity, we know for any integer $n$,

$$\frac{1}{p}\sum_{\ell=0}^{p-1} (\omega^\ell)^n = \delta_p(n) 
\stackrel{def}{=}
\begin{cases}1,& n \equiv 0\pmod p\\0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
This implies for any integer $k \in \{\;1,2,\ldots,p\;\}$, we have

$$-\frac{1}{p}\sum_{\ell=0}^{p-1}\omega^{-k\ell}\log(1-z\omega^\ell)
= \frac{1}{p}\sum_{\ell=0}^{p-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}( \omega^\ell )^{n-k}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta_p(n-k)\frac{z^n}{n}
= \frac{1}{p}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{np+k}}{n+\frac{k}{p}}
$$

This leads to
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+\frac{k}{p}}\right)z^{np}
= - \sum_{\ell=0}^{p-1}\left(z^{-p} - z^{-k}\omega^{-k\ell}\right)\log(1-z\omega^\ell)
\tag{*1}$$
Since the sequences $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+\frac{k}{p}} \sim O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\;$, the series on the LHS converges absolutely as $z \to 1^{-}$. 
The RHS is a finite sum, the only term that may cause trouble is the term for $\ell = 0$.
It is clear the logarithm singularity from the $\log(1-z)$ get killed by the
$z^{-p} - z^{-k}$ factor as $z \to 1^{-}$. This allow us to take the limit $z \to 1^{-}$ in
$(*1)$ and get
$$\mathcal{S}_{k/p} \stackrel{def}{=}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+\frac{k}{p}}\right)
= \frac{p}{k} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+\frac{k}{p}}\right)\\
= \frac{p}{k} - \sum_{\ell=1}^{p-1}\left(1 - \omega^{-kl}\right)\log(1-\omega^\ell)
$$
Using the identities

$$\sum_{\ell=1}^{p-1}\log(1-\omega^\ell) = \log p
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\sum_{\ell=1}^{p-1}\omega^\ell = -1$$
The sum reduces to
$$\begin{align}
  &\frac{p}{k} - \log(2p)  + \sum_{l=1}^{p-1}\omega^{-k\ell}\log\left(\frac{1-\omega^\ell}{2}\right)\\
= & \frac{p}{k} - \log(2p) + \sum_{l=1}^{p-1}
\left( \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k\ell}{p}\right) - i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k\ell}{p}\right)
\right)\left(\log\sin\left(\frac{\ell\pi}{p}\right) + i\pi\left(\frac{\ell}{p}-\frac12\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$
Using another set of trigonometric identities
$$\sum_{\ell=1}^{p-1}\frac{\ell}{p}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k\ell}{p}\right) = -\frac12\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{p}\right)
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\sum_{\ell=1}^{p-1}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k\ell}{p}\right) = 0
$$
We finally get
$$
\bbox[4pt,border:1px solid blue]{
\mathcal{S}_{k/p} =
\frac{p}{k} - \log(2p) -\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{p}\right) + 
\sum_{l=1}^{p-1} 
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k\ell}{p}\right) \log\sin\left(\frac{\ell\pi}{p}\right)
}
\tag{*2}
$$

On the wiki page of [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), there is a formula for digamma function at $\frac{k}{p}$.

$$\psi\left(\frac{k}{p}\right) = -\gamma - \log(2p) - \frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{k\pi}{p}\right) + 2\sum_{\ell=1}^{\lfloor\frac{p-1}{2}\rfloor} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k\ell}{p}\right)\log\sin\left(\frac{\ell\pi}{p}\right)$$

Compare this with what we have in $(*2)$, we can simplify our sum as

$$\mathcal{S}_{k/p} = \frac{p}{k}+\psi\left(\frac{k}{p}\right) + \gamma
= \psi\left(\frac{k}{p}+1\right) + \gamma$$

Replace $\frac{k}{p}$ by $a$, this matches the result derived in another answer.

Comment: A creative application of series multisection. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\mbox{How does the closed form for}\
     \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n} - {1 \over a + n}}\
     \mbox{look like ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \!\!\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n}\! - \!{1 \over a + n}}
> &\!=a\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{a + n}}
> \!=a\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 1 + a}\pars{n + 1}}
> =\!a\,{\Psi\pars{1 + a} \!-\! \Psi\pars{1} \over \pars{1 + a} - 1}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) $\ds{\bf\mbox{6.3.1}}$
>   and we used [identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm)
>   $\ds{\bf\mbox{6.3.16}}$.

$$\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n} - {1 \over a + n}}
=\Psi\pars{1 + a} + \gamma} = {\rm H}_{a}
$$

> $\ds{\gamma = -\Psi\pars{1}}$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) $\ds{\bf\mbox{6.1.3}}$.
>   $\quad\ds{\gamma \approx 0.5772156649\ldots\quad}$ $\ds{{\rm H}_{a}}$ is a [generalized Harmonic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Applications).

Comment: Looks good, but not what I was looking for. Can express it that in the terms given in the question?

Comment: @draks... There isn't way to escape from the ${\large
\bf{\tt\mbox{Harmonic Number}}}$. It's even suggested by the question.

Comment: So you say there is no rule to generate the $t_{p,k}$ terms, that show up in my example? Unbelievable...

Comment: @draks... I'll think about it. Now, it's too late. Tomorrow I can make some comment about. Thanks.

Comment: @draks... $\tt\color{#66f}{\mbox{@achille hui}}$ [already pointed out](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/865155/85343) the connection between my answer and your expected result. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Write your expression as the limit at $x \to 1$ of
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}  \frac{p x^{pn}}{pn} - \frac{p x^{pn+1}}{pn+1}.$$

If we differentiate this power series, we get
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} p x^{pn - 1} - p x^{pn} 
=
p x^{p-1} \frac{1-x}{1 - x^p}. 
$$
Integrating this (say via a partial fraction decomposition)
and then choosing the constant of integration so that you get
zero when $x = 0$ gives a formula for the original power series.
Now putting $x = 1$ gives the value you want.

E.g. if $p = 2$, we have
$$2 x \frac{1}{1+x} =  2 - \dfrac{2}{1+x},$$
whose desired integral is 
$$2x - 2\log (1+x),$$
and so the value of the sum in this case is $2-2\log 2.$

E.g. if $p = 3$, we have
$$3 \frac{x^2}{1+x+x^2} = 3 - 3\frac{1+x}{1+x+x^2} = 3 - \frac{3}{2} \frac{2x+1}{1+x+x^2} - \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{3/4+ (x+1/2)^2},$$
whose desired integral is
$$3 x - \frac{3}{2}\log(1+x+x^2) - {\sqrt{3}}\arctan\bigl(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigr)+\sqrt{3} \frac{\pi}{6},$$
and so the value of the sum in this case is
$$3 - \frac{3\log 3}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3} \pi}{6}.$$

I didn't try to find the general formula here.  One part of mathematics where it is
worked out is the theory of special values (at $s = 1$) of Dirichlet $L$-series.

[Added: it seems that between when I began writing this yesterday, and when I finally got a chance to finish and post it now, other answers with related derivations have appeared. Oh well.]

Comment: I appreciate your approach. Thanks +1...