# How to evaluate this infinite series? $\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r + \frac{1}{3})}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**The question is to find this infinite series:**

$$ \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r + \frac{1}{3})} = \; ? $$

---

**I have tried applying the Riemann sum to the Integral technique as follows:**

Assuming the lower and upper boundaries (*a* and *b*) are 0 and 1. Now, we know that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} {f(x)} \; dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r = 1}^{n} f(\frac{r}{n}) $$

Therefore,

$$ \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r(r + \frac{1}{3})} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{r(r + \frac{1}{3})} $$

$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \frac{n}{r(r + \frac{1}{3})} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r = 1}^{n} \frac{n}{r} \frac{1}{({r+\frac{1}{3}})} $$

I'm stuck here.

Is there a different approach to this problem? Or, could this problem be solved this way?

---

**Edit:** Given in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486398/how-to-evaluate-this-infinite-series-sum-r-1-infty-frac1rr-fra/4486405#comment9409383_4486398) below, does not answer my question. The answer is completely incomprehensible to me.

Comment: This sum doesn't really have anything to do with Riemann sums. I'm not sure what level of math you are comfortable with, but with complex analysis you can find the answer is $9-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi-\frac{9}{2}\ln (3)$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%281%2F%28r%28r%2B1%2F3%29%29%2Cr%2C1%2Cinfty%29

Comment: @QC_QAOA I specifically used the Riemann sums because it is an infinite series, and after matching it to the $\frac{r}{n}$ format, we could reduce it to a definite integral, and then evaluate.

Comment: Riemann sums $\leftrightarrow$ require sums of functions of the form $f(r/n)$. Your sum is not of this form so it doesn't turn into a Riemann sum

Comment: @QC_QAOA Yes, that is where I'm stuck. It's not doable, seemingly.

Comment: @QC_QAOA I'm curious of how you apply directly Complex Analysis  for this question.

Comment: @zwim Does not seem so. The final answer approximates ~1.33.

Comment: @Parasseux_Nguyen The basic idea is to use the formula in the link below. You can transform sums over rational functions into residues of a related function of (that includes $\cosh(\pi z)$). With a little finagling you can solve any sum of rational functions this way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#An_infinite_sum

Comment: @QC_QAOA : Ah ok. Got it. Nice approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using partial fractions, we have $$\dfrac{1}{r(r+\tfrac{1}{3})} = \dfrac{3}{r}-\dfrac{3}{r+\tfrac{1}{3}}.$$ Then, by using the identity $\dfrac{1}{n} =  \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}\,dx$, we have $$S:= \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{r(r+\tfrac{1}{3})} = \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{3}{r}-\dfrac{3}{r+\tfrac{1}{3}}\right] = 3\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{r-1}-x^{r-2/3}\right)\,dx.$$ Because every term is positive, we can then interchange the order of the summation and integral. $$S = 3\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}\left(x^{r-1}-x^{r-2/3}\right)\,dx.$$ The summation is of a geometric series which converges for $|x| < 1$ (i.e. almost everywhere on $[0,1]$), so we have $$S = 3\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1-x^{1/3}}{1-x}\,dx.$$ Now, just substitute $x = u^3$, $dx = 3u^2\,du$ and use a trigonometric substitution to finish.

Comment: Very slick, +1.

Comment: Using the integration you mentioned, the solution to this problem is correct! Also, I did not know the $\frac{1}{n}$ identity. Thanks for that, too.

Comment: Clear and simple

Comment: It seems that you gave a similar answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/869707/42969. I'm voting to close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The logarithmic derivative of the Gamma function, a famous special function generalizing the factorial operations to complex inputs, is called the digamma function, $\psi$. For complex $z$, it can be shown (from the Weierstrass factorization of the gamma function) that
$$\psi(z+1) = - \gamma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z}{n(n+z)}$$
So note
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z}{n(n+z)} = \psi(z+1)+\gamma$$
and so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{n(n+\frac{1}{3})} = \psi(\frac{4}{3})+\gamma$$
Thus
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+\frac{1}{3})} = 3(\psi(\frac{4}{3})+\gamma)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, I'm not sure what those unique functions do right now. I will have a look into them sometime later.

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, for $a>0$, we can compute the partial sum
$$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^n \frac 1{r(r+a)}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$S_n=\frac 1 a  (-\psi (a+n+1)+\psi (a+1)+\psi (n+1)+\gamma )$$ and using the asymptotics
$$S_n=\frac{\psi(a+1)+\gamma }a-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{ (a+1)}{2 n^2}-\frac{ (a+1) (2 a+1)}{6
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$